# Gravar hora atual em um arquivo .txt

Tags: javascript

Como fazer um post online de uma variável em um determinado TXT? Tentei o seguinte, mas não deu certo:

```
function post(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "POST", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send("Hora Atual" + $hora);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

post("http://www.example.com/aviso.txt");
```

Comment: [é isso que você quer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081146/how-can-i-create-and-send-a-text-file-over-xmlhttprequest-or-ajax)

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, não entendi..

Comment: Pode definir melhor o que "não deu certo" quer dizer?

Comment: Não é possível, olha a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17417/5082) abaixo.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha, ele não colocou nada dentro do arquivo...

Answer (score 5):

O javascript é uma linguagem [client-side](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_client-side) e não é possível interagir com arquivos dessa forma.

Você precisa de alguma linguagem [server-side](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_server-side) por exemplo: [php](http://www.samuelcorradi.com.br/manipulando_arquivos_php.html), [asp.net](http://www.macoratti.net/aspn_txt1.htm)

Comment: Tem certeza @Silvio Andorinha ? Porque eu tenho uma outra função em JAVA SCRIPT na qual eu busco uma linha dentro de um txt hospedado. Ela funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Talvez seja apenas mais um POG.

Comment: O que o @SilvioAndorinha quis dizer é que não é possível recuperar variáveis "POST" de um arquivo txt você precisará de um servidor web rodando alguma tecnologia server-side apos isso você até pode por exemplo como no apache configurar que arquivos txt irá executar PHP mas tbm não vejo necessidade pra isso.

Comment: @user7605 [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17415/postar-uma-variavel-num-arquivo-txt/17417?noredirect=1#comment32953_17417)

Answer (score 5):

Se o que você está tentando fazer é gerar um .txt a resposta é: **Sim, é possível.**

O HTML5 permite o uso do atributo `download` em tags `<a>` que nada mais faz do que *forçar* o conteúdo daquele link a ser baixado. Exemplo:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" download="data.txt" id="download">Download da data</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mt, data, download;
mt = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,';
data = new Date();
download = mt + encodeURIComponent(data);

document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('href',download);
```

**[`Exemplo`](http://jsfiddle.net/bdz2z/)**

### Mais sobre o atributo `download`:

- Pode ser utilizado para fazer download de imagens geradas no lado cliente via `base64`;
- Não sobrescreve cabeçalhos HTTP (se uma diretiva do cabeçalho entrar em confilto com ele, o cabeçalho prevalece);

Comment: na verdade eu não preciso fazer download, eu preciso enviar um POST com a data atual através do JavaScript para um TXT hospedado em um servidor, através de HTTP...entende ?

Answer (score 1):

Pela sua explicação muito resumida, o que eu pude entender é que você quer simplesmente gravar um determinado *timestamp* num arquivo de texto.

Se você logo de início pensou em AJAX, você deve ou pelo menos deveria ter em mente que é preciso haver um aplicação do lado servidor (PHP, ASP, Python...) para efetuar a manipulação do *filesystem*, efetivamente criando esse arquivo.

Então, qual o propósito de dar toda essa volta, envolver JavaScript, obstruir a sua aplicação, se um simples link apontando para um determinado URL responsável pela criação do arquivo já é suficiente? Um exemplo com PHP, haja vista ser popular e eu não saber qual sua linguagem de servidor:

```
<a href="/path/to/my/resource.php">Gerar Aquivo</a>

<?php file_put_contents( 'aviso.txt', date( 'd/m/Y - H:i:s' ) . "\n", FILE_APPEND );
```

Desconsiderando verificação de permissões de escrita, resolvi um problema específico em duas linhas, uma de HTML e uma de PHP.

Caso eu esteja enganado, edite sua resposta e forneça mais detalhes. No ajude para nós o ajudarmos.